# Will expanding the recursive term change the time complexity?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I saw a webpage about 2 weeks ago and no matter how much I searched my browsing history I couldn't find it. It was something like this:
The time complexity of f(n) = 2f(n-1) is SOMETHING, but the time complexity of f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1) is OTHER_THING that I can't remember.
When I read it it sounded right because in the first case f(n-1) is being calculated once (and then multiplied by 2), but the second one actually tries to compute f(n-1) twice, so its time complexity should be higher.

Is this true? If so, what would be SOMETHING and OTHER_THING?

P.S. To me by this analytics, SOMETHING should be linear, because at each level of the recursion tree we only calculate one thing and then multiply it by 2. So it will be a tree on n levels, with two operations (one for calculating the next f, and one for multiplying by 2) at each level. So that's O(2n) = O(n).
For OTHER_THING it's exponential, because the recursion tree has n levels and at each level we have 2 calculations of the next f. So that's regular O(2^n).

Comment: What are you *actually* asking here, for the link to that webpage, or if your conclusions are correct? They *are*, but the origin of that factor of 2 in `O(2n)` is  dubious.

Comment: The reference would be nice-to-have, but I my main question here was if my conclusions were correct. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
func(integer n)
    if n == 1
        return c;
    return func(n - 1) + func(n - 1)
```

For the above code recurrence equation is equal to `T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 1) + c`. If we expand this recurrence equation we have `sum {2^i}` s.t `1 <= i <= (n - 1)`. This equation is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and simply the algorithm is `O(2^n)`.

But bellow code runs in `O(n)`since it hit every number between `1` an `n` just once. Here the recurrence equation is `T(n) = T(n - 1) + c`.

```
func(integer n)
    if n == 1
        return c
    res = func(n - 1)
    return 2 * res
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the conclusion I had. So it is correct. The reason I was unsure was that most of online websites try to explain the complexity of f(n) = 2f(n-1) using Master theorem and so they end up having exponential complexity. But my understanding is if we write it this way (2*recursive term), it won't get expanded (i.e. drawing two children for the true would be wrong). So to me most of these websites are very misleading.

Comment: @Tcan Yes, But consider that the master theorem target is to solve the recurrence equation. Here, you talk about two different implementations which each one has its recurrence equation. What I want to show in my answer was you must think about rec equation...

Comment: Yes I agree with that and understand your solution. The reason I mentioned master theorem was that many resources use it to find SOMETHING, where I think it's actually not applicable for it. It's only applicable for OTHER_THING, because of the implementation difference you mentioned.